# How to add a PDF file to another PDF file after a given page?

Tags: pdf

I would like to add an existing PDF file to another existing PDF file after a given page and not necessarily at the end of the file. How can I do this in Linux without degrading the quality of the PDF file?

To be  clear, my scenario is this: I got PDF file, called file_2.pdf, which I would like to add to another PDF file, called file_1.pdf. The file file_1.pdf has got, let's say, 100 pages and the file file_2.pdf is made up of three pages named a, b and c. I would like to add file_2.pdf after page 35 of file_1.pdf, so that the resulting file's pages are in this order: 1, 2, 3, ..., 32, 33, 34, 35, a, b, c, 36, 37, 38, 39, ..., 98, 99, 100.

It is very important for me that the resulting file not lose any quality in the process.

Comment: With `pdftk`, it *should* be as simple as `pdftk A=file_1.pdf B=file_2.pdf cat A1-35 B A36-end output out.pdf` - but I can't test that atm

Comment: As steeldriver outlines, this is trivially possible using `pdftk`. Try it and see. And the command looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

I often use pdf2ps to convert pdf to poscript.

Then I use psselect and psmerge to select pages and concat them.

Then I use ps2pdf to convert the result back to pdf.

On my computer I see pdfjoin which should do the trick, from what I read from its man page.